# Use layout constraints for Xcode Scene Editor to lay out sprites similar to Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, autolayout, skscene

Xcode Scene Editor doesn't seem to offer a way to define layout constraints like with Storyboard so that you can use Scene Editor to visually place and organize static sprites (similar to how you can arrange UIButtons with Storyboard).

Could someone confirm these things are not possible with Scene Editor:

1) Position sprites relative to other sprites and the scene using constraints (i.e., center Sprite A relative to Sprite B)?

2) Assuming #1 *is* possible, then adjust layout constraints and sprite sizes based on device?

Comment: Constraints the way you are thinking does not make sense in Sprite Kit,  but yes  there is SKConstraints, which handle 1),  2) does not work or make sense.  This is why the scaleMode exists

Comment: @Knight0fDragon can you kindly explain why they make no sense for static sprites (i.e., ones that won't move after initial placement)?

Comment: because your scene size is designed to be a static size, not one that adjusts

Comment: @Knight0fDragon yes but ours is one that is static

Comment: That makes no sense,  skscenes are designed to be static sizes. You do not lay them side by side,  sprites are meant to float in the scene,  so to auto layout it would be impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't layout constraints in Sprite-kit similar to UIKit constraints where you for example flag auto-layout and **all elements** are re-positioned.

In this place it might not make sense in a context where you can have long backdrops with characters who constantly change their size, objects that disappear or reappear, other elements involved by the laws of physics.
As commented by Knigh0fDragon this is the reason for which `SKSceneScaleMode` exists

> The modes that determine how the scene’s area is mapped to the view
>   that presents it

```
enum SKSceneScaleMode : Int {
    case Fill
    case AspectFill
    case AspectFit
    case ResizeFill
}
```

However in Sprite-kit there are `SKConstraints`:

> An SKConstraint object describes a mathematical constraint on a node’s
>   position or orientation. Constraints are attached to nodes; after a
>   scene processes any actions and physics interactions, it applies
>   constraints attached to nodes in its node tree. Use constraints to
>   ensure that certain relationships are true before a scene is rendered

So, in other words, `SKConstraint` are used to limit the position and orientation of particular nodes, for example it can be used when you want your player stay or run to a particular position and you have some reference points/elements that the player must follow.

An example:

```
let range = SKRange(lowerLimit:50, upperLimit:150)
let leftConstraint = SKConstraint.distance(range, toNode:guardrail)
car.constraints = [leftConstraint]
```

Comment: Thanks so much but these constraints aren't definable within Scene Editor,. correct? Yes, it's understood why constraints don't make sense for all cases, but there are certainly ones where sprites are fixed in size and position and could be defined via layout constraints.

Comment: Correct, about the last question I don't understand what do you mean about "via layout constraints", are you referring to UIKit elements or Sprite-kit elements?

Comment: sprite kit elements

Comment: Look this link http://stefansdevplayground.blogspot.it/2014/11/how-to-implement-space-shooter-with_11.html